# AWS: Call to getSessionToken() on AWSSecurityTokenService results in HTTP 403

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to receive temporary security credentials for a session in an EC2 instance and use the following code

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider instanceCred = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance();
AWSCredentials creds = instanceCred.getCredentials();

AWSSecurityTokenService sts_client = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
"https://sts-endpoint.amazonaws.com", Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.toString()))
.build();

GetSessionTokenResult session_token_result = sts_client.getSessionToken();
Credentials session_creds = session_token_result.getCredentials();
```

Getting the AWSCredentials and calling AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder works just fine, but calling getSessionToken() always ends up in:
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: null (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null; Proxy: proxy.abc.de)

Alternatively I tried, as suggested in the AWS documentation:

```
GetSessionTokenRequest session_token_request = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
GetSessionTokenResult session_token_result = sts_client.getSessionToken(session_token_request);
```

But that ended up with the same error.

Any idea on how to solve this problem is truly appreciated. Might be a configuration problem, but I'm lost...

Cheers
akay

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be a matter of running "unset https_proxy" on the command line to get things going...